# Are there official character sheets for the Skills & Powers book?

Tags: adnd-2e, character-sheets

The AD&D 2E (2.8) *Player's Options* books, specifically the *Skills & Powers* book, have character build information, but not the character sheet to parallel the build.

Is there a character sheet for this build available somewhere? Or would I need to create it?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

### There was no official sheet

However, a search for "skills and powers character sheet" returns a plethora of fan-created ones.

Answer (score -1):

I had forgotten a game of which I was afforded a character sheet for the Player's Options build. I found a few from the search that were simple, though. Here is the one I had from a prior game.[[image: page1page2]